# htaccess turn on https and www BUT only when live, not locally

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I would like to have `.htaccess` code that adds `https` and `www` to my URLs – but only when my site is live, not when I am developing locally on my computer.

I have the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(?::\d+)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

But this doesn't appear to be adding the `www` when my site is live. So for example `https://example.com` doesn't have the `www` and all the links are broken. For example `https://example.com/about` just gets a 404 Not Found error message.

Thanks for any help. I don't understand `.htaccess` files/code.

EDIT / UPDATE

Comparing the code to other code, should it be the following?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(?::\d+)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: What is the hostname when developing locally? Are you using `localhost` on a non-standard port?

Comment: I'm using MAMP and port 8888. So in my local browser I type in http://localhost:8888/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Comparing the code to other code, should it be the following?
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(?::\d+)?$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
> ```

Yes.

Your original rule explicitly *removed* the www subdomain. If you had requested `http://www.example.com/` (note HTTP), you would have been redirected to `https://example.com/` (HTTPS + non-www). But nothing would happen if requesting `https://www.example.com/` - the canonical URL (the rule is skipped because the 2nd and 3rd *conditions* fail).

The `%1` backreference contains the match from the first capturing group in the preceding *CondPattern*. eg. Given the *CondPattern* `^(?:www\.)?(.+)$` then `%1` contains whatever is matched by `(.+)` (the first *capturing* group), ie. the hostname, less the optional `www.` prefix.

There is no difference between testing `%{HTTPS} off` or `%{HTTPS} !on` - the result is the same.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the erroneous redirect will have been cached by the browser.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost(?::\d+)?$ [NC]
> ```

Checking for a port number would seem to be unnecessary here. This will fail if you are using `localhost` on the standard port (80 or 443) since the port number will be omitted from the `Host` header. Something like `!^localhost` would suffice, or perhaps `!^localhost($|:)` if you happen to using a domain name that starts `localhost`!

Comment: That appears to have worked. MAMP default is port 8888 so I've had to leave in the code checking for a port number (I changed the port to 80 in MAMP, but when I visited http://localhost:80 in my local browser it said it was forbidden)

Comment: @user2991837 "...so I've had to leave in the code checking for a port number" - My suggestion is a more general regex, so would work whether there is a port number or not.